# Calling functions inside a map() function in React render()

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dictionary, this

This is a follow up to my previous question, but how do I call a function inside React's render() method, if I have a map inside that.

Example (this code is inside a class that extends `React.Component`):

```
getItemInfo(item){
  return `${item.Something} ${item.SomethingElse}`
}

render() {

return (
 <div className="someDiv">
    {
      collection.map(function (item) {
        return <div> {item.Name} {this.getItemInfo(item)} </div>
    })
  }
 </div>
);

}
```

No matter what I try I always end up getting "this.getItemInfo() is not a function".

I did a `console.log` on `this` inside my `map()` function and it was infact refering to the Window object, but I can't seem to find a way to change that.

I tired:

- defining `getItemInfo` as function getItemInfo(){..}
- passing `this` as a second parameter to my map function
- calling `this.getItemInfo = this.getItemInfo.bind(this)` in react's component constructor
- calling `.bind(this)` after `getItemInfo(item)`

And a couple other things....

None worked. I am fairly new to JavaScript's `this` reference, and I cant seem to figure it out.

I read some answers here related to using this inside `render()` but none of them seemed to work for me.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

```
collection.map(function (item) {
    return <div> {item.Name} {this.getItemInfo(item)} </div>
})
```

So, the scope of `this` inside your `function(item)` is not the scope of your React Component.

If you use arrow function `() => {...}` instead of `function() {...}` you will have access to `this` of React.Component.

Try this

```
collection.map((item) => (
   <div> {item.Name} {this.getItemInfo.call(this, item)} </div>
))
```

To read more about scope of `this` in javascript, you can read here: http://javascriptissexy.com/javascript-variable-scope-and-hoisting-explained/

To read about arrow functions and scope of `this`, refer to "No separate this
" section of https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

Comment: Hmm, this still says this.getItemInfo() is not a function.

do I have to do anything special to my function declaration in order to get it to work

Comment: Hey, I have updated the answer with `this.getItemInfo.call(this, item)`. If you use this.func() inside render(), you need to bind it.

Comment: Just tried it. I now get cannot read property of undefined :(

Comment: Edit: I manged to get it work. I had an inner .map(function) that I also needed to change. Thank you for the detailed answer :)